# when use the Flutter mobile Simulator the input for the text field become white which makes it impossible to see the words

Tags: flutter, mobile, simulator, white-framework

when using the Flutter mobile Simulator, the input for the text field becomes white which makes it impossible to see the words.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37bKq.png)

Comment: because the background is white,  now the input font is also white, so it's impossible  to see the input in the text field.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your `TextField` widget and change your text color to black.

```dart
style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
```